# How to get response from Google+ Share API about whether user shared link or not

Tags: google-plus

I want to check whether the user shared my content in google plus or not, I tried `onendinteraction` callback but user may click close button instead of share button so i need to detect user originally shared content or not?

Comment: possible duplicate of [google+ share and onendinteraction - no confirm](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18375727/google-share-and-onendinteraction-no-confirm)

Answer (score 0):

Just noticed this linked question. I answered it on [another post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18375727/google-share-and-onendinteraction-no-confirm/) but here it is again -

According to [Google Developer](https://developers.google.com/+/web/api/rest/latest/activities/list#try-it) page for their web platform, it seems you can tap into the current users activities list using a javascript code similar to -

```js
var request = gapi.client.plus.activities.list({
  'userId' : 'me',
  'collection' : 'public'
});

request.execute(function(resp) {
  var numItems = resp.items.length;
  for (var i = 0; i < numItems; i++) {
    console.log('ID: ' + resp.items[i].id + ' Content: ' +
      resp.items[i].object.content);
  }
});
```

The online tool to generate and test the query end point is there on the [Developer Page](https://developers.google.com/+/web/api/rest/latest/activities/list#try-it)

Generate and append a custom query string to the end of the link your user is sharing, the JSON returned from the end point can be parsed to check if that particular link has been shared on the users activity stream.
The JSON returned looks like this -

```
{
 "items": [
  {
   "title": "",
   "published": "2015-06-12T16:39:11.176Z",
   "url": "https://plus.google.com/+UserID/posts/PostID",
   "object": {
    "content": "",
    "attachments": [
     {
      "objectType": "article",
      "url": "http://www.example.com"
     }
    ]
   }
  }
 ]
}
```

If the link with the custom query is there in the attachments section of one of the returned items,Voila! Its been shared.